# "the an" appear together as an article?

Tags: grammar, articles

In this [article](https://statswithr.github.io/book/the-basics-of-bayesian-statistics.html) the author writes that

> If **the an** individual is at a higher risk for having HIV than a randomly sampled person from the population considered, how, if at all, would you expect P(Person tested has HIV ∣ ELISA is positive) to change?

I thought it would just be a typo but in the preceding text it appears again:

> If **the an** individual is at a higher risk for having HIV than a randomly sampled person from the population considered, ...

I wonder if it is grammatical?

Comment: The same error, made twice.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey OK. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Four times if you include “the the”.

Comment: Probably was a cut and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many grammatical errors and misspelled words in that document.

I would suggest that you don't use it to hone language skills.